About Dafny loop invariant errors
The following code is the answer I came up with for the following problem. However, there are two main errors. By the way, this problem is problem 17 in Chapter 13 of the book "PROGRAM PROOFS" (author K. Rustan M. Leino).
A consecutive stretch of equal elements in a sequence is called a plateau. (a) Define a ghost predicate Plateau(s, lo, hi) to say that s[lo..hi] is a plateau. (b) Specify a method that, given an integer sequence s, returns the length of the longest plateau in s. (c) Implement the method.
ghost predicate Plateau<T>(s: seq<T>, lo: int, hi: int)
  requires 0 <= lo <= hi <= |s|
{
  forall i, j :: lo <= i < j < hi ==> s[i] == s[j]
}

method LongestPlateau<T(==)> (s: seq<int>, lo: int, hi: int) returns (L: int)
  ensures 0 <= L <= |s|
  ensures forall lo, hi :: 0 <= lo <= hi <= |s| && Plateau(s, lo, hi) ==> L >= hi - lo
  ensures exists lo, hi :: 0 <= lo <= hi <= |s| && Plateau(s, lo, hi) && L == hi - lo
{
  var i: int := 0;
  L := 0;
  
  while i < |s|
    invariant 0 <= i <= |s|
    invariant 0 <= L <= |s|
    invariant forall lo, hi :: 0 <= lo <= hi <= i && Plateau(s, lo, hi) ==> L >= hi - lo
    invariant exists lo, hi :: 0 <= lo <= hi <= i && Plateau(s, lo, hi) && L == hi - lo
  {
    var f: int := i;
    

    while i < |s| && s[f] == s[i]
      invariant 0 <= f <= i <= |s|
      invariant forall j :: f < j < i ==> s[f] == s[j]
    {
      i := i + 1;      
    }
    
    if L < i - f {
      L := i - f;
    }
  }
  
}

For invariant forall lo, hi :: 0 <= lo <= hi <= i && Plateau(s, lo, hi) ==> L >= hi - lo, I get an error saying that the loop cannot be maintained, and for invariant exists lo, hi :: 0 <= lo <= hi <= i && Plateau(s, lo, hi) && L == hi - lo, it seems that the loop cannot be entered and cannot be maintained.
Regarding the [Invariant exists] error, I think that the reason the loop cannot be entered is probably because Plateau is not true before the loop.
I think so, but I don't know how to make it true. Furthermore, I don't know why [Invariant forall] gives an error. I don't know why [Invariant exists] cannot be maintained inside or after the loop. I would really appreciate some advice on resolving these errors.
The hope is that it will simply provide a behavior that answers the problem.

You've done well and you're close.
For the existential
Here are three ways of dealing with it.
The existential has to be proved both before the (outer) loop and at the end of the (outer) loop. To prove something like exists lo, hi :: ..., you sometimes have to give the verifier a hint, to tell it a "witness" for the existentially bound variables lo and hi that shows that the existential is true. You can do that by writing an assert with the body of the existential, but plugging in specific values for lo and hi. That can look like
assert 0 <= 0 <= 0 <= i && Plateau(s, 0, 0) && L == 0 - 0;

just before the loop. Note that I have used the values 0 for lo and 0 for hi. You can simplify this assertion to just assert Plateau(s, 0, 0);. By giving this assertion before the loop, the verifier will try to prove it (which it can do), and then this form of the assertion will allow the verifier to realize that 0 and 0 are good witnesses for lo and hi.
You would do the same at the end of the loop body. There, the values you need for lo and hi and f and i, so adding assert Plateau(s, f, i); at the end of the loop will do the trick.
For the one at the end of the loop body, there's something else you can do. Instead of expressing the inner-loop invariant as forall j :: ..., you can use your definition of the Plateau predicate. Then, this invariant for the inner loop would be invariant Plateau(s, f, i). I think that looks nice. And also, by writing the invariant that way, the condition Plateau(s, f, i) is known to hold immediately after the inner loop, which is enough for the verifier to prove the existential of the outer loop. In other words, if you write the inner-loop invariant in this way, then you don't need the assertion at the end of the outer-loop body.
A third approach is to keep lo and hi as variables in the program and to update them. Let me call the variables l and h, to make sure there's no confusion with the lo and hi in the other quantifiers. So, instead of writing the existential as a loop invariant, write
invariant 0 <= l <= h <= i && Plateau(s, l, h) && L == h - l

Introduce l and h as local variables and initialize them before the outer loop:
var l, h := 0, 0;

and update them inside the if statement at the end of the outer loop:
l, h := f, i;

Now, you don't need either of the two assertions. (Note, since l and h are needed only for the proof and not in the compiled program, you can declare them as ghost:  ghost var l, h := 0, 0;.)
For the universal
Whereas the problem with the existential was just convincing the verifier that values for such lo and hi really exist, the problem with the universal in your program is something different. Consider an arbitrary iteration of the outer loop. Suppose the given sequence s is a single, long plateau, say, of length 100. Every iteration of the loop starts in a state where the loop invariant holds. One such state would be that i and L are both 20. Note that these values do satisfy the loop invariant. Now, the effect of the next iteration would be that the inner loop figures out that there's a plateau of length 80 starting at index 20. The if statement at the end of the outer loop would now update L to 80. But this value does not satisfy the universal in the loop invariant, because there are longer plateaus among the elements seen so far.
The issue I described in this scenario is that your invariant doesn't say anything about that the new plateau--the one between f and i--consists of an element that wasn't immediately before this plateau. So, what you need to do is to add another loop invariant to the outer loop to express the fact that  the plateau starting at index f couldn't possibly have started any earlier.
Good luck!

Sorry for the late reply. Thank you for your reply. Thanks to you, most of the problems have been solved.
